# ggthemes scale_colour_solarized("blue") gives "Error in [[: subscript out of bounds" when applied to a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
plot <-
    ggplot(tot_costs,
           aes(period, total_cost, colour = team, group = team)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    ylab("") +
    xlab("Year") +
    # Commented working code theme_minimal() +
    theme_solarized(light = FALSE, base_size = 16) + scale_colour_solarized("blue") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45),
          legend.title = element_blank())
```

When I replace the theme_solarized by theme_minimal, everything is working, but when I try to apply theme_solarized/scale_colour to the plot, I get a "Subscript out of bounds error". I wonder if it's related to the color palette, maybe there are too many "teams" for the colors available. However, it's the solarized theme is working fine with other plots with the same teams

Comment: I'm also suspecting there's too few colors in this theme.

Comment: The error I get says that the maximum number of colors available is 8. Note that this is not the solarized theme, but the scale_colour_solarized that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation for `scale_color_solarized()` it says to:

> See solarized_pal() for details.

Looking into `?ggthemes::solarized_pal`, it says:

> This palette supports up to seven values.

I guess in this case your easiest choice is to use a different color scale.

By the way, distinguishing more than around seven colours can prove difficult if they are close togheter in a plot, so think about giving an additional aesthetic to your team variable (e.g. shape).